# Gradual performance degradation of data import using Spring batch, EhCache, and Hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-batch, ehcache

I am using the Spring MVC 4, Spring Batch 3, Hibernate 5, and Ehcache 2.8. Using Spring Batch, I am importing a lot of data from CSV to the DB using Hibernate at chunks of 1000. For additional information, data from the CSV refers to other tables that is why i have a lot of DB queries before the actual insert.

At first, the interval between chunks are small, between 10 seconds. Gradually, after around 100,000 items, the interval between the items are more than 1 minute. I suspect that it is some caching issue as this is gradual degradation. My current hibernate stats are

- 2nd Level Cache Hit %: 97.8839177750907
- Query Cache Hit %: 54.206282344445775
- Query Max Time: 4.08s at a query used in the import

Here is my ehcache.xml configuration

```
<defaultCache 
    eternal="false"
    timeToIdleSeconds="180" 
    timeToLiveSeconds="240" 
    maxEntriesLocalHeap="10000"
    maxEntriesLocalDisk="50000" 
    >
    <persistence strategy="localTempSwap" />
</defaultCache>

<cache name="org.hibernate.cache.internal.StandardQueryCache" 
    maxEntriesLocalHeap="10000"
    maxEntriesLocalDisk="50000"
    eternal="false"
    timeToIdleSeconds="180"
    timeToLiveSeconds="240"
    >
    <persistence strategy="localTempSwap" />
</cache>

<cache name="org.hibernate.cache.spi.UpdateTimestampsCache" 
    eternal="false" 
    maxEntriesLocalHeap="0"
/>
```

[EDIT] and here is the source code for the batch job

```
@Bean
@StepScope
public static FlatFileItemReader<CsvPayment> paymentReader( @Value( "#{jobParameters[fullPathFileName]}" ) String pathToFile,
                                                            @Value( "#{jobParameters[delimeter]}" ) String delimeter,
                                                            @Value( "#{jobParameters[skipItems]}" ) Long skipItems,
                                                            @Value( "#{jobParameters[limitItems]}" ) Long limitItems )
{
    FlatFileItemReader<CsvPayment> reader = new FlatFileItemReader<>();

    reader.setResource( new FileSystemResource( pathToFile ) );
    reader.setEncoding( GlobalConstants.UTF8 );
    reader.setMaxItemCount( limitItems.intValue() );
    reader.setLinesToSkip( skipItems.intValue() );
    reader.setLineMapper( new CsvPaymentLineMapper( delimeter ) );

    return reader;
}

@Bean( "importPayment" )
public Job importPayment( ItemReader<CsvPayment> paymentReader )
{
    return jobBuilderFactory.get( "paymentReader" ).incrementer( new RunIdIncrementer() ).flow(
        paymentStep1( paymentReader ) ).end().build();
}

@Bean
public Step paymentStep1( ItemReader<CsvPayment> paymentReader )
{
    return stepBuilderFactory.get( "paymentStep1" ).<CsvPayment, OccupancyPayment> chunk( CHUNK_SIZE ).reader(
        paymentReader ).processor( itemProcessor ).faultTolerant().listener(
            new ChunkListenerImpl( logger ) ).writer( itemWriter() ).build();
}

@Bean
public HibernateItemWriter<OccupancyPayment> itemWriter()
{
    HibernateItemWriter<OccupancyPayment> itemWriter = new HibernateItemWriter<>();
    itemWriter.setSessionFactory( sessionFactory );
    itemWriter.setClearSession( true );
    return itemWriter;
}
```

Hopefully, someone could point me to the right direction. Thanks.

Comment: clear the 1st level cache. Each entity is added to the first level cache and each time you issue a query hibernate checks the first level cache (the session/entitymanager) for dirty objects. The more objects there are the more time it takes.

Comment: @M.Deinum The HibernateItemWriter, which I am using in Spring Batch, says in the API that it is clearing the first level cache at each write. I'll update the post to provide my source code for the batch job.

Comment: Your processor is missing.

Comment: What `JobRepository` are you using?

Answer (score 0):

The session cache is growing and making your app slower and consuming more memory.

Try this:

```
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

for ( int i=0; i<100000; i++ ) {
    Customer customer = new Customer(.....);
    session.save(customer);
    if ( i % 20 == 0 ) { //20, same as the JDBC batch size
        //flush a batch of inserts and release memory:
        session.flush();
        session.clear();
    }
}

tx.commit();
session.close();
```

Example taken from [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/reference/en/html/batch.html#batch-inserts) and I confirm to you we use the same solution and it works good.

The only downside of the solution is that sometimes you may get `NonUniqueObjectException` from Hibernate. It comes as a consequence of the `session.clear()` which makes all Hibernate instances *detached*. In such a case, you definitely need to read [this](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/objectstate.html) and probably call `session.refresh(instance)`.

Comment: This is not spring batch. As you know, Spring batch can split the commits into chunks making the data to appear gradually. Using a one time commit for 250,000 inserts is not ideal for my case